# Why is my factory getting an injector error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui

I can't seem to figure out why I can't load my AuthFactory factory in my controller.  The syntax looks correct to me.  Also note, the portalAPI factory is built out the same way as the AuthFactory, howver it is being injected correctly.  If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it:

```
    (function() {

    var app = angular.module('contactAuthApp');

    //////////////////////////
    //  BEGIN - CONTROLLER
    //////////////////////////

    var ContactAuthController = function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $state, $timeout, portalAPI, $location, AuthFactory) {
        $scope.resetcode = $location.hash();
        $scope.loggedIn = false;
        $scope.errormsgheader;
        $scope.errormsgbody;
        $scope.successmsgheader;
        $scope.successmsgbody;
        $scope.errDialogHidden = true;
        $scope.successDialogHidden = true;

        var onUserComplete = function(response) {
            for (var i in response.contact) {
                var obj = response.contact[i];
                $rootScope.user = obj;
            }
            $rootScope.companies = response.companies;
            //$rootScope.databases = response.databases;

            for (var i in response.databases) {
                var obj = response.databases[i];
                //$scope.secondaryData.push(obj);
                $rootScope.databaseName = obj.databasename;
            }


            for (var i in $rootScope.companies) {
                var obj = $rootScope.companies[i];
                //$scope.secondaryData.push(obj);
                $rootScope.companyID = obj.ID;
                $rootScope.companyOptions = [{
                    name: obj.name,
                    id: obj.ID
                }];
            }

            $scope.loggedIn = true;
            portalAPI.getCompanyBrands($rootScope.companyID, 'active').success(goTest).error(goCharts);
        };

        var onForgotPasswordComplete = function(response) {
            /*  Show/hide windows and alerts    */
            $scope.errDialogHidden = true;
            $scope.successDialogHidden = false;
            $scope.successmsgheader = response.success.heading;
            $scope.successmsgbody = response.success.body;
            $timeout(function() {
                $state.go('/');
            }, 4000);
        };

        var goWelcome = function(response) {
            $state.go('welcome');
            //$state.go("welcome");
            var data = response.companybrands;
            $rootScope.brandOptions = [];
            for (var i in data) {

                var obj = {
                    name: data[i].Name,
                    id: data[i].ID
                };

                $rootScope.brandOptions.push(obj);
            }
        };

        var goTest = function() {
            var g = AuthFactory.isAuthenticated();
            //$state.go("testing");
        }

        var goCharts = function() {
            $state.go("chart");
        }

        var goDashboard = function() {
            $state.go('dashboard');
        }

        var onError = function(response) {
            var error = response.error;
            $scope.errDialogHidden = false;
            $scope.errormsgheader = error.heading;
            $scope.errormsgbody = error.body;
            $scope.successDialogHidden = true;
        };

        $scope.authenticate = function() {
            portalAPI.getUser($scope.username, $scope.password).success(onUserComplete).error(onError);
        };

        $scope.newPassRequest = function() {
            portalAPI.getForgotPassword($scope.username).success(onForgotPasswordComplete).error(onError);
        };

        $scope.newPassRequestVerify = function() {
            portalAPI.getForgotPasswordVerify($scope.username, $scope.resetcode, $scope.newpassword, $scope.confirmnewpassword).success(onForgotPasswordComplete).error(onError);
        };

        $scope.submitparameters = function() {
            $rootScope.startDate = $scope.startDate;
            $rootScope.endDate = $scope.endDate;
            $rootScope.clientdb = $rootScope.databaseName;
            $rootScope.companyid = $scope.companyOptions.id.id;
            $rootScope.brandid = $scope.brandOptions.id.id;

            // The number of milliseconds in one day
            var ONE_DAY = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

                // Convert both dates to milliseconds
            var date1_ms = Date.parse($rootScope.startDate)
            var date2_ms = Date.parse($rootScope.endDate)

            // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
            var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

            // Convert back to days and return
            $rootScope.diffDays = Math.round(difference_ms / ONE_DAY)
            $state.go('dashboard');
        }
    };

    //////////////////////////
    //  END - CONTROLLER
    //////////////////////////


    /////////////////////////
    //  BEGIN - FACTORIES
    /////////////////////////

    var portalAPI = function($http) {

        var getUser = function(username, password) {
            return $http({
                    url: "https://staging.revguard.net/portalapi/index.php",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    responseType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        "authentication": [{
                            "apiusername": "jaime",
                            "apipassword": "summit",
                            "apicompanyid": 3
                        }],
                        "controller": "Contact",
                        "method": "contactAuthenticate",
                        "params": [{
                            "username": username,
                            "password": password
                        }]
                    }
                })
                .success(function(response) {
                    //console.log("success"); console.log(response)
                    return response;
                })
                .error(function(response) {
                    //console.log("error"); console.log(response);
                    return response;
                });
        };

        var getCompanyBrands = function(companyid, status) {
            return $http({
                    url: "https://staging.revguard.net/portalapi/index.php",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    responseType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        "authentication": [{
                            "apiusername": "jaime",
                            "apipassword": "summit",
                            "apicompanyid": 3
                        }],
                        "controller": "CompanyBrand",
                        "method": "getCompanyBrands",
                        "params": [{
                            "companyid": companyid,
                            "status": status
                        }]
                    }
                })
                .success(function(response) {
                    return response;
                })
                .error(function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
        };

        var getForgotPassword = function(username) {
            return $http({
                    url: "https://staging.revguard.net/portalapi/index.php",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    responseType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        "authentication": [{
                            "apiusername": "jaime",
                            "apipassword": "summit",
                            "apicompanyid": 3
                        }],
                        "controller": "Password",
                        "method": "forgotPasswordTrigger",
                        "params": [{
                            "username": username
                        }]
                    }
                })
                .success(function(response) {
                    return response;
                })
                .error(function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
        };

        var getForgotPasswordVerify = function(username, resetcode, newpassword, verifynewpassword) {
            return $http({
                    url: "https://staging.revguard.net/portalapi/index.php",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    responseType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        "authentication": [{
                            "apiusername": "jaime",
                            "apipassword": "summit",
                            "apicompanyid": 3
                        }],
                        "controller": "Password",
                        "method": "forgotPasswordVerify",
                        "params": [{
                            "username": username,
                            "resetcode": resetcode,
                            "newpassword": newpassword,
                            "verifypassword": verifynewpassword
                        }]
                    }
                })
                .success(function(response) {
                    return response;
                })
                .error(function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
        };

        return {
            getUser: getUser,
            getCompanyBrands: getCompanyBrands,
            getForgotPassword: getForgotPassword,
            getForgotPasswordVerify: getForgotPasswordVerify
        };

    };

    var AuthFactory = function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        var authToken = false;

        var isAuthenticated = function() {
            return authToken;
        };

        var login = function(state) {
            //return (typeof(state) == 'string') ? $state.go(state) : $state.go("route1");
        };

        var logout = function() {
            alert("You've been logged out");
            $state.go("route1");
        };

        return {
            isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
            login: login,
            logout: logout
        };
    };

    ////////////////////////
    //  END - FACTORIES
    ////////////////////////


    ////////////////////////
    //  BEGIN - DIRECTIVES
    ////////////////////////



    ////////////////////////
    //  END - DIRECTIVES
    ////////////////////////


    app.controller("ContactAuthController", ContactAuthController);
    app.factory("portalAPI", portalAPI);
    app.factory("AuthFactory", AuthFactory);

})();
```

Comment: You can't inject `$scope` into a factory because there is none. `var AuthFactory = function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {` and use the `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`.

Comment: Thanks, seemed to do the trick

Comment: Cool, will post it as an answer so you are able to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't inject `$scope` into a factory because there is none. Try `var AuthFactory = function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {` and use the `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` or pass the scope from the `controller` to your service.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

> **$scope:** Controllers are always associated with a point in the DOM and so are
>   provided with access to the scope at that point. Other components,
>   such as services only have access to the singleton $rootScope service.